# How to combine the values in a column of dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a dataframe with two column. I want to concatenate the values in a second column and return a string. How can I do this in R?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `paste` with the appropriate delimiter.  Here, I am using `''`. You can specify it to `-`, `_` or anything else.

```
 paste(df$Col2, collapse="")
```

If there are `NAs` you could use `na.omit`

```
 paste(na.omit(df$V2), collapse="")
```